# JSON data structure - JSON to objects - best practice

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, typescript

I am struggling with my web-application design using JSON, ASP.NET, typescript/javascript and AngularJS.

**In Short:**
*I need a best-practice for sending data from the server to a client via JSON, using the     JSON-string on the client side to create objects.*

I have a WebServerAPI project (ASP.NET) with the following structure:

- Controllers

  - DataController (REST API)
- Model

  - A
  - Type

**The model classes:**

```
public class A {
    public property int Id {get; set;}
    public property string Name {get; set;}
    public property Type Type {get; set;}
}

public class Type {
    public property int Id {get; set;}
    public property string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The id of each model class belongs to an id in a database table (primary key).

**The DataController structure:**

```
public class DataController : ApiController {
    // ...
    // GET api/a
    public IEnumerable<A> Get()
    {
        // fetches all As from the database
        // the facade creates instances of A and Type as required
        // (if A has a 'Type' the Type will also fetched an set)
        return facade.GetAll<A>();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The Get() Method of the DataController returns a JSON result.

**The JSON result looks like the following:**

```
[
    {"Id":1,
     "Type": {"Id":1, "Name":"name1"}
    },
    {"Id":2,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },
    {"Id":3,
     "Type": {"Id":1, "Name":"name1"}
    }
    {"Id":4,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },
    {"Id":5,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },  
]
```

As you can see in the JSON data some As share the same Types. Although this is valid JSON, I wonder if this is the best practice to send data.

**Wouldn't it be better to send something like this:**

```
[
    {"Id":1,
     "TypeId": {"Id":1}
    },
    {"Id":2,
     "TypeId": {"Id":2}
    },
    {"Id":3,
     "TypeId": {"Id":1}
    }
    {"Id":4,
     "TypeId": {"Id":2}
    },
    {"Id":5,
     "TypeId": {"Id":2}
    },  
]
```

So we get only the Id of the Type. But then we have to request all available Types to identify which Type has to be set in the corresponding As. Which may be bad? I think this might be slow, because I have to send two queries.

**A third option may be sending all available Types and the As in the same JSON result.**

```
[
    {"Types": 
        [
                {"Id":1, "Name":"name1"},
                {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"},
        ]
    },
    {"As":
        [
            {"Id":1,
            "TypeId": {"Id":1}
            },
            {"Id":2,
             "TypeId": {"Id":2}
            },
            {"Id":3,
             "TypeId": {"Id":1}
            }
            {"Id":4,
             "TypeId": {"Id":2}
            },
            {"Id":5,
             "TypeId": {"Id":2}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So I am wondering if there is a best-practice for this. Sending the same object (Type) over and over again as a nested object in A seems quite "stupid".

Especially if I convert the JSON-string into Typescript objects.

**Without any "storage/cache" logic I create the "same" object over and over again:**

```
export class A {
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;
    public Type: Type;

    public static fromData(data: any): A {

        var a = new A();
        a.Id = data.Id;
        a.Name = data.Name;
        a.Type = Type.fromData(data.Type);

        return a;
    }
}

export class Type {
        public Id: number;
        public Name: string;

        public static fromData(data: any) : Type {
            var type = new Type();
            type.Id = data.Id;
            type.Name = data.Name;

            return type;
        }
}

// AngularJS controller
export class AListCtrl {
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    public As: A[] = [];

    constructor(private $scope, private $http) {
        $scope.AListCtrl = this;

        $http.get('http://localhost/api/a').success((data) => {
            var as: A[] = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var aData = data[i];
                var a = A.fromData(aData);

                as.push(a);
            }

            this.As = as;
        });
    }
}
```

Creating different objects which represent the same Types seems just wrong. Because I work a lot with references in other languages (C#, Java, C++). Using this way of de-serializing the data and creating the objects allows no usage of references at all (*maybe this is wrong in web-applications?*). And I also think, generating a lot of useless objects instead of one per Type is a waste of memory and CPU time.

Quite a long post, but I hope it explains my problem well.

**To summarize it:** *I need a best-practice for sending data from the server to a client via JSON, using the JSON-string on the client side to create objects.*

Comment: I usually have the c# view model exactly match the javascript view model. I find it makes it easier to maintain, leads to a faster development time, and in the future when I make a change it's not a big deal (to me this is more important than saving a few bytes of network traffic). If you're not developing an application where every byte counts, or passing massive amounts of data, you shouldn't worry about it. You're already saving lots of bytes by passing a json string instead of doing a full page reload when viewing a new page.

Comment: @dhsto Unfortunately I have to deal with a lot of data (about 1kk objects (As)). But as you can see in the typescript code, I use the same class structures in C# and in typescript.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to define the JSON representation that makes the most sense for your client application, and then make sure that the data is being sent in that format. I would create a custom serializer, either using the built-in [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or possibly the one provided by [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Just using the built-in serializer doesn't seem to give ideal results.

Comment: ok, defining my own json structure would make sense for me too. Which option would you prefer? 2 or 3?

Comment: I would go with option 3 as it cuts down on the round-trips to the server, and might(?) simplify your client side code a bit.

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb in API design is to craft your json response to fit your client-side needs.  I am sure some REST purists would disagree but in real world applications reducing XHR requests and client side processing is preferable to adhering to a dogmatic approach to resource modeling.

Letting your database / server side object model abstractions leak into your client will end up costing you time and effort.  If you serialize your data to fit your client needs then you can keep that interface even if your backend implementation changes.

Comment: When I want to work with references in typescript, I need to map the data anyway. So 1 object per Type, and the As referencing the different Type objects. But maybe working with references is wrong anyway?

Comment: Your client side models don't necessarily need to map to your server side models. Sharing models can be a great timesaver but sometimes it makes sense to to alter or flatten them for performance and usability.

Comment: @Scoot Puleo: Hmm.. I agree with that. I could of course provide 2 ways to get data. One which contains everything like in option 1, and another for my typescript/javascript implementation, which helps me to map the data to objects (again, to work with references).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question and I don't think there is ONE right answer that fits all the possible cases.

In general the third option is the one I would choose first. It is correct because allows you not to duplicate the same data (the Type) and it is efficient because all data is available with one request, which is good to reduce the overhead of XHR requests to the server.

Now, both other options may have some merit for various scenario. If the dataset is small, for example, you may not care to duplicate your Types data.

One think I would keep in mind is to choose the best representation that fit your front-end code. Unless this is a generic API you want to share to other clients I recommend making the back-end and front-end working well together to get the best speed while keeping your code simpler on the client side.

hope it helps

Comment: nice answer - like the other answers, it seems like I should go with option 3 if I only use it for an internal API. Well, that's actually the case, so I think I go for option 3

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that the JSON is send is Data-Driven. In this sense it should be independent of the client, or the database structure you are using.

For example, if you retrieve some `Foo`'s, the JSON should contain all the relevant information that a client `might want to use`, otherwise you'll end up rewriting your data providing API for every potential client. I tend to try to view it from the 3th party's perspective;

- do I need to know something about the backing database: no.
- do I want the API to provide me lots of relevant information with little effort: yes.

So to sum it up:

```
[
    {"Id":1,
     "Type": {"Id":1, "Name":"name1"}
    },
    {"Id":2,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },
    {"Id":3,
     "Type": {"Id":1, "Name":"name1"}
    }
    {"Id":4,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },
    {"Id":5,
     "Type": {"Id":2, "Name":"name2"}
    },  
]
```

Seems valid in your case.

Comment: I use relational databases frequently and this way of representing data doesn't fit into the concept of relational databases. So that may be reason why I'm not comfortable with this way of data representation :)

Comment: @bakunin: I can imagine. It is definitely a different mind set. But ask yourself this question: if you are using a other persons API, do you really want to query/combine data in a relational way? Or do you want a nice looking container with all the info that is relevant? I would go for the latter, unless the amount of data is exceptionally large of course.

Comment: @bakunin: an addition: maybe the Type::Id is not relevant for the client. For example, if types are read-only or not to be edited through this kind of API call. If it isn't, you can omit it.

Comment: Right, but on the other hand, when I am creating objects out of the data, I would map the data anyway. So instead of 100 equal objects with the same content, I would map it to one object (working with references).

Comment: @bakunin: true, a valid argument. But will you provide your clients with the javascript to merge/combine the JSON data? Well, it's still a matter of taste I guess. The bare minimum, from a API's point of view, is that the data structure is clear in it's context.

Comment: Yes I would provide the client the necessary code to put the data together. And yes, therefore I have to update this code when the API changes. But as you can see in the typescript code, I want to use classes anyway.. so I have to do that anyway.. right? (web noob ;) )

Comment: @bakunin: ok, then it seems you are good to go. Keep in mind that it is always possible to extend your JSON objects. So changes in your classes will not necessarily lead to changes in the script library. Good luck :)